# Can we accept a unique value for a column in all the tables for a certain database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table using input form and I want a column to be unique not only for one table but for all the tables in the database. How do I make it happen

```
$app=$_POST['application'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$reference=$_POST['ref'];
$sql="CREATE TABLE $app (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ref VARCHAR(100) NULL UNIQUE,
name TEXT  NULL)";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
if($result)
{
$sqla = "INSERT INTO $app (ref,name) VALUES ($reference,$name)";
$res = mysqli_query($db,$sqla)
```

Here what I want is this reference number to be unique in the entire database and not just for one table.

Also please note that I have not given $db

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design